# to_mesh() in blender 3

Tags: python, blender

in previous blender versions, it was possible to get the actual position of a vertex with to_mesh():

https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-get-vertices-coordinates-from-animated-mesh/565581/4

Unfortunately this function does not work in blender 3, does it? Is there an alternative approach to get the vertex coordinates with modifiers and shape keys applied? Thanks in advance!

Greetings

Answer (score 3):

This minimal example is working for me in blender 3.0.0:

```
import bpy

# get absolute position of a vertex from an object with shapekeys (and other transforms)
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
obj = bpy.context.object.evaluated_get(dg)

mesh = obj.to_mesh(preserve_all_data_layers=True, depsgraph=dg)
co = mesh.vertices[0].co
co_final = obj.matrix_world @ co
print(co_final)
```

It is based on approaches from ideasman42 and iceythe Kaio in this older posts:
https://blenderartists.org/t/get-mesh-data-with-modifiers-applied-in-2-8/1163217
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/how-can-i-get-vertex-positions-from-a-mesh